# Deployment Laravel 5.4 - DigitalOcean - Nginx LEMP (16.04)

Tags: nginx, dns, laravel-5.4, digital-ocean

i'm deployment my laravel project in digitalocean, actually i have this situation:

**DNS RECORDS - GODADDY**

[image: My domain in pointed to my IP of dig]

digitalocean ip server 104.131.16.82

**DNS RECORDS DIGITALOCEAN**

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7jiH.png]

**SERVER BLOCK ENABLED**

i enabled my default server block in "/etc/nginx/sites-available/default" and created link in "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default" like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/mysite-test.com/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;
        return 301 $scheme://mysite-test.com$request_uri;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
        location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

i followed this tutorial to install: https://gist.github.com/naveenyagati/5deec8fc40a2faaff20c629362dddf39

Actually if i go to 104.131.16.82 download a file, i don't know why, it doesn't work well, maybe i have error in server block? or DNS records?
thank you for your help!

Comment: This statement will cause a redirect to some other server: `return 301 $scheme://dixart.com$request_uri;`. The `location` blocks below it, will not be consulted.

Comment: dixart.com is my site, let me update code

Comment: The `return 301` will cause a redirect loop. You should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have deployed using **ONE CLICK APP INSTALL** in **Digital Ocean** you have to edit the file named "**digitalocean**" in "/etc/nginx/site-available" directory not the "**default**" file for changes to take effect. If not the default LEMP landing page would be shown there.

Command to edit the main file,in digital ocean ONE CLICK APP INSTALL

> sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/digitalocean

Now replace the contents of the file with the following code

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /var/www/laravel/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name <Your Domain name / Public IP Address>;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

> Replace the **server_name** part with your
>   server IP or domain name

Further reference could be found in the following gist that I have made
https://gist.github.com/naveenyagati/5deec8fc40a2faaff20c629362dddf39